# Python Jupyter Packages Not being found

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Okay so I've been trying to figure this out for a while and I'm so lost.

I'm trying to import sqlalchemy in my jupyter notebook but I get this error:

> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\typing.py in 
> 36     from typing_extensions import Annotated as Annotated  # 3.8
> 37     from typing_extensions import Concatenate as Concatenate  # 3.10
> ---> 38     from typing_extensions import (
> 39         dataclass_transform as dataclass_transform,  # 3.11,
> 40     )
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'dataclass_transform' from
> 'typing_extensions'
> (C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\typing_extensions.py)

But in that exact folder path I have these versions of

```
typing_extensions:
typing_extensions-3.7.4.3.dist-info
typing_extensions-4.0.0.dist-info
```

From the error message it looks like its wanting version 3.11 but that version doesn't exist according to their release history:
https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/#history

In the same folder I have versions 2.0.12 and 1.3.20 of sqlalchemy installed. I really have no idea what to try at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems like `typing_extensions` and `sqlalchemy` are not compatible.

You can try uninstalling and installing `typing_extensions`.

You can also try -

```
pip install typing-extensions --upgrade
```

You can refer to this [link](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-importerror-cannot-import-name-required-from-typing-extensions).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Apparently I needed typing_extensions upgarded to at least version 4.4 after I did that I was able to get it to work.